# Visual Studio WinJS Phone project can't add .dll reference?

Tags: visual-studio

Sorry if the question is generic, I am trying to add external references to my project. e.g. the player framework for WinJS. However, whenever I try to add a reference the references are filtered. Only *.winmd files are shown.

Every online explanation I find shows that the reference manager shows both .dll and .winmd files (e.g. https://playerframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%3a%20WP8%20Smooth%20Streaming%20Player&referringTitle=Windows%20Phone%208%20Player%20Documentation).

However, in both my VS2012 and VS2013Express installation, the reference manager filters only *.winmd files.

Am I missing something?

Comment: http://playerframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Windows%208%20Player:%20Install%20and%20configure%20-%20HTML/JavaScript

Comment: @HansPassant I am not trying to add that framework. I'm trying to add a .dll file. Only reason I included the link was to show that it shows '.dll' file extension in the add reference window. Where mine does not.

Comment: Adding DLLs to the references is useful for statically compiled languages like C# or VB.NET.  Javascript is not.